# Why doesn't 100% width/height work on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

If you have the chance to enter to http://toniweb.us/gm in your phone you will see that the dimensions are...wrong.

Acording to the css:

```
html, body{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

It should be using the whole of it.

And, I added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2.0"  />
```

But I am not so sure what this affects.

In addition, the website is optimized to >= 1024 pixels.  Is there a way to adapt iPhone to this? Perhaps by scaling somehow?

Any hint would be very helpful.

Comment: What is "a bit personal" supposed to mean in your question title?

Comment: I just looked at it on my iPhone and I can't say the dimensions are wrong.  It kinda looks like I'd expect given the huge left column as it currently appears.

Answer (score 1):

Tried:

```
html, body{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I guess that above code will do the job ;)
And I think your goal was to see only the grey sidebar on the iphone right?

Comment: my goal was to see it as more similar to a desktop computer view as posible, i need to release it this week and i will do the proper mobile version next month

Comment: If you want to resize everything you need to do way more then just width: 100%...,
You shoudl need to use js then which looks at the window size and resizes the elements :/

Anyway take a look at 'mediaqueries' may that help you ;)

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial ;) http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Comment: hey thanks! but i am making a bit of use of it already http://toniweb.us/gm/css/media.css

Comment: Try doing a media query with max-width: 1024px; then make then use the css I showed in my answer above to get the stuff positioned to teh left and right edge of the screen (100%).

Comment: Btw I get 2 horizontal scrollbars because your image slideshow is pulling outside the container, make sure to use overflow: hidden;