# 100% screen width not working properly in Salesforce1 on iPhone

Tags: ios, css, salesforce

I'm working on an app for Salesforce1. S1 has a menu on the left and a news feed on the right, both hidden until revealed by swiping the screen to the left or right.

My body width is set to 100%, but when I swipe to the left or the right, the content slides from side to side but the actual screen does not, as if the content is floating around inside the body. This only occurs on the iPhone. On Android, the 100% width works perfectly.

If I give my body a width of 310px, it swipes fine.

Would anyone have any suggestions or advice?

```
 html,body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        min-width:310px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        color: #000;
        font: normal 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;     
        font-size: 12px;
 }

.content{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your `<HEAD>`?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,  user-scalable=no">
```

and adding in your html,body styling rule: `margin:0;`

Comment: I did, no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: and resetting the margins to 0?
`margin:0;`?

Comment: Yep, thats too. Very frustrating.

Comment: and to your body,html `overflow:hidden;` ?
Safari is simply a tough mistress... you're not alone in your quest ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646958/why-doesnt-100-width-height-work-on-iphone

Comment: Cheers for the help Michael... I shall continue on my adventure! For the time being, I think I'm gonna set the width to 310px and use media queries to pick up the slack.